# 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.gcs' is not a package

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I'm upgrading to Airflow 2.0 and I'm seeing the following error when trying to import GoogleCloudStorageHook

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.gcs.GCSHook import GoogleCloudStorageHook

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.gcs.GCSHook'; 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.gcs' is not a package
```

Comment: Dis you install google provider?

Comment: @Elad yes I have this: apache-airflow-providers-google==2.2.0 in my requirements.txt file

Answer (score 0):

when airflow < 2.0 use

```
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import GoogleCloudStorageHook
```

airflow >= 2.0

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.gcs import GCSHook
```